# Loading UITableView form UIView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am working on navigation based application in which i can navigate to many views starting from default UITableView which is starting view in application template.

I have added another UIView and added tableView control on that UIView.

I am calling that view form one of the many views on a button click. Its showing the view but not populating the data in the table. And I also want to handle the event when user taps on the cell of the table of that view. Below is the Code I am using on button click:

if(self.lstView == nil)

{

ListViewController *viewController = [[ListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ListViewController" bundle:nil];

```
    self.lstView = viewController;

    [viewController release];
```

}

[self.navigationController pushViewController:lstView animated:YES];

self.lstView.title = @"Select";//@"System";

[self.lstView.tblList.dataSource fillList];

Below is the fillList function code:

-(NSArray *)fillList

{

NSArray *tempArray = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Item 1" , @"Item 2" , nil]autorelease];

return tempArray;

}

I am pretty new in Iphone programming and don't have much understanding.

Helping with detailed description and code will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try setting tableviews datasource and delegate property
tblList.dataSource=self;
tblList.delegate=self;

Rest of the work you have to do in delegate methods of the table view..

Comment: where do i define and implement datasource and delegate methods?